# VS Code, GDB remote debugging and Linux/Windows path characters

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code, gdb, remote-debugging, openocd

Simple question I hope. I'm using VS Code with the C/C++ extension running on Windows for remote debugging an ARM Cortex M0 board via OpenOCD running on Linux. This all works wonderfully well, with a single exception: path characters.

The problem is the `${workspaceFolder}` macro. Since VS Code is running on Windows it seems to always use `\` as a path delimiter. See error picture below. Obviously hardcoding the full path using `/` works but makes the launch.json highly machine specific.

Anyone know how to remap the path character?

TAIA.

launch.json for anyone who wants a working reference:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Debug",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "logging": { "engineLogging": true },
            "program": "R:/src/embedded/mcuxpresso/ASCH5_LPC/flash/ASCH5_LPC.axf",
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "miDebuggerPath": "r:/apps/gcc-arm/bin/arm-none-eabi-gdb.exe",
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "targetArchitecture": "arm",
            "launchCompleteCommand": "exec-run",
            "setupCommands": [ 
                { "text": "-target-select remote 192.168.1.99:3333", "description": "connect to target", "ignoreFailures": false },
                { "text": "-file-exec-and-symbols R:/src/embedded/mcuxpresso/ASCH5_LPC/flash/ASCH5_LPC.axf", "description": "load file", "ignoreFailures": false}, // this works
                //{ "text": "-file-exec-and-symbols ${workspaceFolder}/flash/ASCH5_LPC.axf", "description": "load file", "ignoreFailures": false}, // this does not ...
                { "text": "-interpreter-exec console \"monitor reset\"", "ignoreFailures": false },
                { "text": "-interpreter-exec console \"monitor halt\"", "ignoreFailures": false },
                { "text": "-interpreter-exec console \"monitor arm semihosting enable\"", "ignoreFailures": false },
            ],
            "externalConsole": true,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
            }
    ]
}
```

[image]